# Rearranging a table in R

Tags: r

I'm very new to R. I have a set of data that I would like to rearrange in the order of first with last, second with second last, etc. So for example say my data looks like this:

```
user | Event | count |
use1 | start |  1    |
use1 | start |  2    |
use1 | stop  |  3    |
use1 | stop  |  4    |
```

And I would like it to return something like this:

```
user | Event | count |
use1 | start |  1    |
use1 | stop  |  4    |
use1 | start |  2    |
use1 | stop  |  3    |
```

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "in the order of first with last, second with second last"?

Comment: I just fixed up my edits... You can have a look at the example which furthermore clarifies it

Comment: What if there are more than four rows?  What if there are an odd number of rows?  This is a bit broad as it stands.

Comment: are you looking for code to reverse and interweave and by user as well?

Comment: I'm assuming that the rows are an even number for this case and yeah I want to manipulate the rows as a whole

Comment: please take a basic course in R and learn how indices work. This is stuff I teach within the first hour of an R course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that OP is looking to reverse the order of the data.frame and then interweave with the original data.frame and that there are an even number of rows per user, here is a solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(user="use1", Event=c("start", "start", "stop", "stop"), count=seq_len(4))

dt[, {
        #number of rows for this user
        n <- .N

        #generate the row indices by interweaving the ordered with the reverse ordered
        idx <- as.vector(rbind(seq_len(n), rev(seq_len(n))))

        #take only the first half of the indices
        idx <- idx[seq_len(length(idx)/2)]

        #indexing and return
        .SD[idx]

    }, by=.(user)]
```

here is another alternative using `base` package:

```
df <- data.frame(user="use1", Event=c("start", "start", "stop", "stop"), count=seq_len(4))
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$user, function(x) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    idx <- as.vector(rbind(seq_len(n), rev(seq_len(n))))
    idx <- idx[seq_len(length(idx)/2)]
    x[idx,]
}))
```

Comment: Do i need to download anything to use data.table?...I'm working with Rstudio and R

Comment: you will need to install the package using `install.packages("data.table")`

Answer (score 3):

*(Edited after question was updated)*

OK, now that you have updated your question the steps involved are
slightly different:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(user, Event) %>%
    mutate(rank_by_event = rank(count),
           reverse_rank = max(rank_by_event) - rank_by_event + 1,
           pair = ifelse(Event == "start", rank_by_event, reverse_rank)) %>%
    arrange(user, pair, Event)

# Output:
    user  Event count rank_by_event reverse_rank  pair
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>         <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
1   use1  start     1             1            2     1
2   use1   stop     4             2            1     1
3   use1  start     2             2            1     2
4   use1   stop     3             1            2     2
```

It's not totally clear to be whether this should happen within each user or overall, you may want to change `group_by(user, Event)` to just `group_by(Event)` if you're not getting the desired results.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you need `library(dplyr)` too.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake... Can you have a look at my edits

Comment: @tee: OK, i've adapted my answer to match your updated question.

Comment: @marius when i try to run your code i get the following error: Error: could not find function "%>%". Do you know how I can go about solving this? thanks!

Comment: You need the dplyr package. So first a one-off `install.packages("dplyr")`, then make sure you run the `library(dplyr)` line when running the code.