# R rearrange my table in a particular way

Tags: r

I recently started learning R. I basically have a table that I would like to rearrange in a particular way that is difficult for me to explain without an example. So here's the table I got:

```
| user |  event  | Line |

| use1 | enter   |  1
| use1 | enter   |  2
| use1 | login   |  3
| use1 | enter   |  4
| use1 | enter   |  5
| use1 | enter   |  6
| use1 | login   |  7
| use2 | login   |  8
....
```

So basically what I want to do is look for every time the event is equal to login and match it up with the most recent enter that is before it. The resulting table should look like this:

```
| user |  event  | Line |

| use1 | enter   | 2
| use1 | login   | 3 
| use1 | enter   | 6
| use1 | login   | 7
| use1 | enter   | 6
| use1 | login   | 8
...
```

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: If you want to select the rows with only `"login"`for event variable and lets call `dat` to your matrix, you can run `sub.login <- dat[dat$event=="login",]`. The second part is which I don`t understand.

Comment: @R18 I don't just want the "login" I want to pair it with the most recent "enter". For example the very first login occurs at line 3 and this will get the most recent "enter" before it at line 2.. and so on and so forth

Comment: Didn't any answers from the first time you asked this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244308/rearranging-a-table-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick yea it helped with the problem I was having earlier...This question is different and I don't know how to work off the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating the two events into different arrays to find last previous enter event for each login

```
i1 <- which(df1$event == "login")
i2 <- which(df1$event == "enter")
i3 <- unlist(lapply(i1, function(x) c(max(i2[i2 < x]), x)))
df1[i3, ]

    user event Line
2   use1 enter    2
3   use1 login    3
6   use1 enter    6
7   use1 login    7
6.1 use1 enter    6
8   use2 login    8
```